# How to get a list from an excel column which matches an specific value

Tags: python, excel, list, dataframe

[excel example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhUgu.png)

Hello team,
I hope someone can help me. I am really newby to python and I am trying to implement some features about I couldn't find an exact answer for what I need.
I have an excel with a few columns of information. You can see the picture to unserstand better.
I am trying to get a list from one column with the objects which matches with another column.

This is the file (I have removed some rows and columns for better understanding):

```
Centro                IP_Address    Verificado  Ejecutado   Puerto Router       
SW-Cepsa-040-1        10.201.40.94  OK          13-may          Fa0/1                   
SW-Cepsa-40_128-1     10.201.40.158 OK          13-may          Fa0/1                   
SWMarket000-1         10.200.0.251  OK          13-may          Fa0/23     
SWMarket000-2         10.200.0.252  OK          13-may                       
SWMarket000-3         10.200.0.253  OK          14-may                      
SW-Market-005-4       10.200.5.249  OK          15-may                      
SW-Market-005-1       10.200.5.251  OK          15-may                      
SW-Market-005-2       10.200.5.252  OK          15-may                      
SW-Market-005-3       10.200.5.253  OK          15-may
```

My goal is to get a list from ip address from devices which match to a specific date.
I need that list to connect to devices to make some checks.
I have been able to create manually this list and do the things I need, but I am trying to improve this procedure and make it more automatic.
This is what I have at this moment.

```
df = pd.read_excel(path_file, index_col="Ejecutado")
```

[loc fechas varias columnas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiiIx.png)

```
df_por_fecha = df.loc["2020-05-13", ["IP_Address"]]
```

[loc una columna](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VP2Co.png)

I can get just the column that I need, but don't know how to put those "IP_Address" to a list.
I have tried some "tolist()" commands with no luck.

I don't know if I am on the right way.
Any help would be appreciated.
I hadn't written a line in python until last week and I am still trying to learn all these features.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I could do it so I will post the answer, maybe will help somebody else.
I got the list with these procedure:
We set variable to "today".
I have replaced the time because the dates in "Ejecutado" are timestamps (they are not just the date but appear as 2020-05-15 00:00:00)

```
>>> hoy = datetime.today()
>>> hoy
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 15, 20, 53, 43, 593294)
>>> hoy = hoy.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
```

We create a boolean sentence to check if the values from column "Ejecutado" are equals to "hoy".

```
es_hoy = df["Ejecutado"]==hoy
```

We compare all the list

```
>>> print (es_hoy)
0        True
1        True
2       False
3       False
4       False
        ...
1381    False
1382    False
1383    False
1384    False
1385    False
Name: Ejecutado, Length: 1386, dtype: bool
```

Then, we get the new dataframe with the information that matches  today's date:

```
>>> df_hoy = df[es_hoy]
>>>
>>>
>>> df_hoy
              Centro     IP_Address Verificado            Ejecutado  
0     SW-Cepsa-040-1   10.201.40.94         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
1  SW-Cepsa-40_128-1  10.201.40.158         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
5      SW-Cepsa-41-1  10.201.41.158         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
6  SW-Cepsa-41_192-1  10.201.41.222         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
7      SW-Cepsa-42-1   10.201.42.30         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
8      SW-Cepsa-42-1   10.201.42.94         OK  2020-05-15 00:00:00  
[6 rows x 111 columns]
>>>
>>>
```

For last, we put all the ip addresses in a list.

```
>>>
devices = df_hoy["IP_Address"].tolist()
>>>
>>> print (devices)
['10.201.40.94', '10.201.40.158', '10.201.41.158', '10.201.41.222', '10.201.42.30', '10.201.42.94']
```

I am sure there will be a few ways to do this, maybe this is not the best, but I could get the list I need.
Anyway, if someone has any suggestion I will improve the code.
I had a few problems between datetime and timestamps and that's how I fixed them.